# how to configure webpack fullySpecified rule for a package in node_modules folder?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have two javascript repos, one is "mpUtils", a private npm repo, and the second one "main" that uses via npm the "mpUtils" repo.
In both, I am using .mjs as extension, and in both, I have a rule to set fullySpecified: false so in my imports I don't need to put ".mjs" explicitly.
Both projects build well, but the problem is when "main" imports "mpUtils", then I got the error:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './iepModels/index' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
```

How can I define in "main" project a rule that disables the fullySpecified flag but only in the node_modules/utils/index.mjs file?

I tried this in the "main" package.json, but is ignored:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      // failed rule for the imported private package:
      {
        test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/,
        include: '/(node_modules/mpUtils)/', <-- this is where I need help
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: [
            ['@babel/preset-env',
              {
                useBuiltIns: false, // alternative mode: 'entry', 'usage'
                targets: { browsers: 'last 2 versions, not IE 11, not dead' },
                loose: false,
              },
            ],
            '@babel/preset-react',
          ],
        },
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false, // disable the behaviour
        },
      },
```